Users see old data build up on webpage as they use it



Clearly a sportsbook.
Top image is what user should see - the current live lines offered by sportsbook.
Middle and bottom image combine to show view of what they actually see as they scroll down page - combination of current lines offered and old stale lines from several hours earlier or day before.
As the day goes by more and more cached or old data begins to display to the user. They see some or all of the current live lines available, but they also see a bunch of old live lines that are no longer functional. It gets worse as the day progresses. By the end of the day it's so bad the user can almost exclusively see old lines that are not functional. Old lines fill the page to the point where they begin to take the place of what currently should be there rather than simply moving it up or down on the page. Website host can not recreate the issue on their end so they can't troubleshoot it or advise on how to troubleshoot it. The issue happens to large amount of customers on PC, phone, multiple browsers, WiFi/mobile providers. Help?

You haven't really given any technical information, so I'm going to assume these are images. If so, you should put a date parameter so that the image fetches the current version. So if your image is called results.jpg, the caching mechanism will not refresh as much as you needed. However, if you have something like results.jpg?date=202412252003 (Date in Year-Month-Day-Hour-Minute format), it will be cacheable, but as soon as you post a new image, the name will change, and thus it would be freshly obtained from your server.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Apologies. I'm trying to figure out whether this is an issue caused by the people broadcasting the website or if it's a user side issue. And also, how to fix the issue so that the users see exactly and only what they are supposed to see, which are the current available lines and data.

I'm not a technical person. I'm representing the users. There are thousands of us experiencing issues with this sportsbook. When we log into the site in the morning everything looks fine. We see the current offerings and can interact with the site normally. But as the day progresses all this old data starts to pile on and what we see are dozens of old stale lines. The stale lines cloud up the entire page and once it gets really bad we can't even see the current offerings anymore. The sportsbook is trying diligently to figure out the issue, but they themselves can't replicate it.

I have video footage of what it's like when it's really bad. I'm not sure if I'm allowed to link videos here, but if it would be helpful to anyone looking at this let me know and I'll link it.

You need the technical person responsible for the site to provide more information to help you diagnose the issue. What is the server technology (Apache, IIS)? How are headers configured? Is the problem only with caching images or content? etc.
